# make an inner class a friend in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, friend, inner-classes

I want to make an inner class a friend of an unrelated class but this doesn't seem to work (at least in gcc 4.1.2):

```
class A {
    int i;
    friend class B; // fine
    friend class B::C; // not allowed?
};

class B {
    int geti(A* ap) { return ap->i; }

    class C {
        int geti(A* ap) { return ap->i; }
    };
};
```

Comment: Lots of basic errors in your code, please fix those first: no "B::C::geta()", "A::i" is private. "B::C::geti()" is private.

Comment: Just ignore the main function.

Comment: "Just ignore the main function." Incredible. Did it work when you told the linker that?

Comment: OK - but next time go the extra step and make+test an example that has shows nothing but the problem in question. And remember to "accept" answers eventually for good karma :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare `B::C` before using it. The following might work.

*Update:* Ignoring a usable demonstration as requested, here's a way of structuring this (minus the definitions of member functions) that could work, but bear in mind that everything is private as it stands.

```
class A;

class B
{
  int geti(A * ap);

public:
  class C
  {
    int geti(A * ap);
  };
};

class A
{
  friend class B;    // fine
  friend class B::C; // fine too
  int i;
};
```

Then define the getter functions elsewhere:

```
int B::geti(A * ap) { ... }
int B::C::geti(A * ap) { ... }
```

---

Alternative: forward-declare the nested class `B::C` and save one external definition:

```
class A;

class B
{
  int geti(const A * ap) const; // we cannot use A yet!

public:
  class C;
};

class A
{
  friend class B;    // fine
  friend class B::C; // fine too
  int i;
};

int B::geti(const A * ap) const { return ap->i; }

class B::C
{
  inline int geti(const A * ap) const { return ap->i; }
};
```

Comment: OK that works, thanks, but is there really no way of declaring `B::C` by just doing `class B::C;` in the same way we can do `class B;` to declare `B`? Having to put the getters elsewhere is annoying.

Comment: I posted an alternative, but I don't know if that's better.

Comment: @dave - No, you cannot declare nested names like that. In `class B::C` is B a class or a namespace?

Comment: @BoPersson: Either it is declared, or it isn't either. Unfortunately it is not allowed even if you say `class B; class B::C`. C++ does not allow forward-declaring member without defining the containing class.